# optimal spread modeling

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, optimal-control

Here is an interesting case. A bacterium either doubles or transforms into an infectious form with a time-dependent probability $p_n$ and $1-p_n$. Let $X_n$ be the number of duplicate bacteria and $Y_n$ be the number of infectious bacteria in the generation $n$. The host cell dies when,
$$T:=\min\{n:X_n+Y_n\geq c\}.  $$

The process begins with a single divisible individual, so $(X_0,Y_0)=(1,0)$. We want to maximize the number of $E(Y_T)$, how to do this? For example, with a time-independent probability $p$, if $c=3$, then not as complicated as, $E(Y_T)=1-p+2p(1-p)^2+2p^2(1-p)$, and only this expression should be maximized in $p$. But how can we say anything about the general case? Could some programming help?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You mention time-dependent probabilities but your example used fixed probabilities. Also, you will need initial conditions for the process. Finally, you say that you want to maximize $Y_n$ and cannot be maximized per say. Perhaps, you want to maximize $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the probabilities are time dependent, but in a fixed case I just managed to calculate something. The process starts with a single living individual who is divisible, so $(X_0,Y_0)=(1,0)$. And I want to maximize $E (Y_n)$.

Comment: Please update your question with the additional details.

Comment: It's done now! I hope this is understandable!

Comment: To make sure, you want to maximize $\mathbb{E}[Y(T)]$ right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, so the expected value of infectious forms at the time of cell death.

Comment: In this case, that can be cast as an optimal control problem that should be solvable using Dynamic Programming I would say.

Comment: Okay, I get it, but unfortunately I don't understand so much about programming, how could this be done?

Comment: Dynamic programming is not about programming. It is about mathematical optimization subject to dynamic constraints. Check for instance the books by Bertsekas.

Comment: Also, I would need more clarification. When you say that the cell divides, it is one of them that divides (so $X$ increases by 1) or you assume that all of them divide (so $X$ is doubled)? Also, when one $X$ is turned into one $Y$, this $Y$ can not divide, right?

Comment: That's right, the infectious form can no longer divide, and we also assume it can't recover back into a divisible form. Also, each proliferating cell independently decides whether to divide or transform into an infectious form.